# Will Eclipse 3.8 (or Juno) be able to run on Java 9?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno, java-9

My application is based on Eclipse 3.8, and I'd like to know if it will run over Java.

I'm not using a newer version because it has performance issues. From my experience, Eclipse 3.8 is a lot faster compared to any newer versions of Eclipse.

Does someone know something about this?

**UPDATE:** The previous title may suggest that I want Eclipse 3.8 to be able to support the new features of Java 9. But, I really just want to know if I'll be able to run the application over Java 9 JRE.

Comment: So you intend to stay on Juno forever? If I would be you I would rather invest in writing bug reports and getting the things fixed that trouble you on newer versions. In my experience, such backports were often not robust enough. You spend a lot of time trying to get them to do what you want... To finally give in and upgrade to the new version of eclipse. And back then the changes were **not** about a new module system that will affect anything...

Comment: I think you should give neon a shot

Comment: Support for updates to Eclipse 3.8 ended long ago with release 3.8.2. It won't be updated for Java 9.

Comment: It doesn’t even have Java 8 support…

Comment: @GhostCat The target users of my application are extremely sensitive to any changes that affects the performance (the IU performance to be more especific). The experiences with newer versions were pretty bad in that matter. So, I know that soon I'll be forced to change, but, I realy don't need the new features to be supported on Eclipse 3.8. I just need to be able to run the application on the new JRE. But, soon I'll have to try to update again. And, thank you for the answer.

Comment: If you only want to know whether it is *compatible* enough to run an application based on it, you should not ask for special “Java 9 support”. You don’t need special support to *run* an application in a newer Java version and there is no reason to use the same Eclipse version for the IDE platform  as for your application platform. Your customers won’t recognize which IDE you used for development.

Comment: The problem with Eclipse 4.x is that breaks compatibility with some important RCP features that we use, and the new CSS model is sluggish at best! So... i would love to continue using the best eclipse IDE until now (3.8) but with support for JAVA 8!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it works, but only with a small patch.

It fails because the org.eclipse.osgi bundle of Eclipse 3.8 (Juno) has no runtime profiles for Java 8 or Java 9. If you add those it works for me.

I made successful tests with an RCP-based app on target plattform 3.8.2 (http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.2-201301310800/) running under Java 9 Oracle JVM under Windows 7.

What to do:
You have to patch the org.eclipse.osgi bundle:

- strip signing information
- manually add an entry for the Java 9 Runtime Enironment in the profile.list of the bundle and add a JavaSE-1.9.profile definition

E.g.: https://github.com/derWallace/org.eclipse.osgi

But no guarantees that this is a good deal for production!

Comment: We still use Eclipse 3.8 for dev, and have no plans to move to 4.x anytime sooner. Did you encountered any problems with the org.eclipse.osgi patch so far? Just wanted to add JAVA 8 support

Comment: @marcolopes, we used this in production several years without any problems for one of our RCP-based apps.

Comment: Could not make it work properly just by changing the org.eclipse.osgi plugin... Can't access Java 8 classes unless i remove the "minimum execution environments required" for the project (which will cause errors).

Comment: We still use Eclipse 3.8 here too.  I managed to make our RCP start with Java 9 using derWallace's idea.  But with Java 11 the idea does not solve the problem.

Comment: I don't have any problems starting RCP apps with Java8 and above... they remain compatible, AFAIK. What i need is to have support for JAVA 8 inside the IDE! I believe that's "impossible" without messing up a lot of configurations...

Answer (score 3):

No. Oxygen (4.7) and newer only is what's planned. If your performance findings are verifiable and repeatable, file bug reports about them.